# Dlib library - How to change parameters of correlation tracker on Python

Tags: python, c++, dlib

I am using [Dlib](http://blog.dlib.net/2015/02/dlib-1813-released.html) library (originally written using C++), correlation tracker to track multiple vehicles on Python and it is working fine.

Then I wanted to increase the accuracy of the system and there was an [article](https://github.com/davisking/dlib/issues/802)
saying this can be done by changing the parameter "filter_size" of the correlation tracker.

**So my question is how can I change the "filter_size" parameter which is defined on C++ code from the Python code?**

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one way to do this. You have to change variable filter_size in dlib source code and rebuild library again.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an age-old question. but, m questo change DLIB parameters bought me here. So,

1. If you have existing version of Dlib installed using pip, KIndly uninstall it using Command
   pip uninstall dlib
2. Download the dlib package from http://dlib.net/compile.html
3. Unzip the file and then go to the path : \dlib\image_processing
4. Edit the file correlation_tracker.h
5. Change the value
   *explicit correlation_tracker (unsigned long **filter_size = 8**,*
   to your "chosen value". The default was 6. I have changed it to 8 for my purposes.
6. Then follow instructions in the  http://dlib.net/compile.html
   In my case, changing this parameter helped in increasing accuracy where the tracking window was more concise and was wavering much after this change.

Hope this helps any wanderer